# tsconfig messing up node_modules import

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got my `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
  }
}
```

This let's me have simple and easy to read imports for my app and environment code. However Visual Studio Code will now suggest horrible `node_modules` imports. For instance this one:

```
import { AppInsightsService } from '../../../../node_modules/@markpieszak/ng-application-insights';
```

Instead of only:

```
import { AppInsightsService } from '@markpieszak/ng-application-insights';
```

I've tried changing `tsconfig.json` to the following:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"],
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
  }
}
```

I would like my vscode to be able to import `node_modules` as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue with TypeScript 2.9.2.

GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52089

Solution: use Workspace version or wait for an upgrade